# stuck on python codecademy, list + functions

Tags: python, list, function

I am brand new to programming, I have picked python as a first language. I am stuck at this prompt on codecademy. The prompt is to write a function that counts how many times the string "fizz" appears in a list.

For example: fizz_count(["fizz","cat","fizz"]) should return 2.

The code I have written so far is:

```
def fizz_count(x):
    count = 0
    for word in x:
        if word == 'fizz':
            return count + 1
        return count

fizz_count(['fizz','2', 'fizz', 'fizz', 'fizz', '1'])
```

However when running the code I get an error message that says "Oops, try again. fizz_count(['fizz', 'fizz', 1, 'fizz', 'fizz']) returned 1 instead of the correct answer: 4"

Comment: Do you know what `return` does? It ends the current function and returns the value, instead just do `count += 1` so you don't end your `for` loop on just one loop and move the second return back one tab.

Comment: You're returning count for each word in the list. Your code takes an item in the list, checks if it's fizz, adds 1 if it is, then before moving on the the next word returns the count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't return, you should update the count of words that match it. It's OK as a beginner to make mistakes though.
Here is the correct code:

```
def fizz_count(x):
    count = 0
    for word in x:
        if word == 'fizz':
            count += 1
    return count

fizz_count(['fizz','2', 'fizz', 'fizz', 'fizz', '1'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint, list has an attribute called `count` which is used for exactly that purpose

```
def fizz_count(x):
    return x.count('fizz')

print(fizz_count(['fizz','2', 'fizz', 'fizz', 'fizz', '1']))
```

But if you want to stick with what you got, I'm totally supportive on that. You just need to change `count` in place and return `count` after the loop.

```
def fizz_count(x):
    count = 0
    for word in x:
        if word == 'fizz':
            count += 1
    return count

fizz_count(['fizz','2', 'fizz', 'fizz', 'fizz', '1'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The code has some mistakes but don't worry, as a beginner it is ok to make mistakes.

The correct code is:

```
def fizz_count(x):
    count = 0
    for word in x:
        if word == 'fizz':
            count += 1
    return count

fizz_count(['fizz','2', 'fizz', 'fizz', 'fizz', '1'])
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to increment a variable, you have to assign to it as such: `count = count + 1`. By calling `return count + 1` the function ends and returns the value of the variable `count` incremented by 1. Therefore, the first time this code was reached, the function ended and returned `0 + 1`.

This will work:

```
def fizz_count(x):
    count = 0
    for word in x:
        if word == 'fizz':
            count = count + 1
    return count

fizz_count(['fizz','2', 'fizz', 'fizz', 'fizz', '1'])
```

Comment: this helped, ty

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning, you need to update the count of words that match it. Also, semantics could be improved (`words` instead of `x`).

```
def fizz_count(words):
    count = 0
    for word in words:
        if word == "fizz":
            count += 1
    return count

assert fizz_count(["fizz", "blah", "fiz"]) == 1
assert fizz_count([]) == 0
```